# PowerPoint: How can we create an Undo entry for the actions performed on shapes?

Tags: powerpoint, office-js, office-addins, powerpoint-addins, powerpoint-web-addins

**Unexpected behavior of UNDO:**
When we perform certain actions in PowerPoint using OfficeJS it doesn't create an undo stack.
when <kbd>CTRL + Z</kbd> is pressed PowerPoint ignores changes made using API.

**Example**
I'm working on an add-in that performs certain design decisions over slide elements, e.g., changing color of a shape group, then maybe resizing it etc. In case add-in performed many actions at once and <kbd>CTRL + Z</kbd> is pressed it'll vanish all the changes at once.

**The Expected Behavior!**
In older PowerPoint Object Model there was `Application.StartNewUndoEntry` method that could be used to batch certain actions in one UNDO stack.
I couldn't find anything similar in newer API.

**Recreate The Issue**
Here's an example code:

```js
PowerPoint.run(async context => {
    const slides = context.presentation.slides
    const slide = slides.getItemAt(0);
    await context.sync();
    slide.delete()
    await context.sync();
})
```

I used above code in script lab that deletes the first slide, if we create 5 slides and run the code twice it'll leave us with only 3 slides.
Now pressing UNDO or <kbd>CTRL + Z</kbd> should return those slides! that'd be expected behavior but actually those slides are gone permanently!

This is one case...

Another would be: changing the color of the certain shapes, then maybe changing their sizes/positions to make a visualization, then we'll need to create an UNDO entry to undo this group of actions in single undo call. In previous versions it was possible with `Application.StartNewUndoEntry`, How can we achieve same with newer API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Office JavaScript API (OfficeJS) doesn't provide anything for that. You can find a lot of existing issues filed and confirmed related to the Undo operations at https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+undo .

Note, you can post or vote for an existing feature request on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) where they are considered when the Office dev team goes through the planning process.

Comment: Thanks Eugene, I was hoping to find any workaround or if any common API methods trigger undo stack entry by default? I will add to tech community since I didn't find one specific to PowerPoint.